# Как в EF Core сделать modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

В `EntityFramework 6.x`, если у вас было много классов `EntityConfiguration` то вы могли применить их все одной строчкой в `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` кодом вида:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);
}
```

Есть ли подобное `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly` в Entity Framework Core?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51842709/5752652) от участника  [@TanvirArjel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928070/tanvirarjel).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51842709

Answer (score 0):

### Для EF Core <= 2.1

Напишите метод расширения:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
            .Any(gi => gi.IsGenericType && gi.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))).ToList();

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Затем используйте в `OnModelCreating` следующим образом:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
}
```

### Для EF Core >= 2.2

Начиная с EF Core 2.2 вам уже не нужно писать собственный метод расширения, так как был [добавлен](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13014) метод `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly); // Here UseConfiguration is any IEntityTypeConfiguration
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888243/5752652 от участника [@TanvirArjel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928070/tanvirarjel).</sub>

Comment: Зачем `.ToList()`, если далее все равно идёт независимое перечисление?

Comment: + это повалится, если в текущей сборке имеется абстрактный класс, реализующий искомый интерфейс, либо же, собственно, интерфейс, его расширяющий

Comment: В том числе не факт, что у созданного объекта есть метод `ApplyConfiguration`, ибо явную реализацию интерфейсов ещё никто не отменял

Comment: Раз уж перевод вольный, советую исправить косяки автора, ибо с ними ответ очень и очень сырой :)

Comment: P.S. - не заметил, что метод `ApplyConfiguration` вызывается у `modelBuilder`, а не у `configurationInstance`, так что с ним претензия снимается :)